# Fetch API not working on Android/ React Native

Tags: android, xml, react-native, fetch-api

I know the issue was solved by many and I have already checked and tried all the solutions provided by other devs both on blogs and stack overflow, yet nothing works and I still can't fetch data from an API (I use Bubble.io database) on my React Native app. It works just fine on my iOS emulator, but nothing on Android, and I get [TypeError: Network request failed] on each attempt. A first release of the app was done and it works well on production and that's why I don't get it. I have set `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` already in my AndroidManifest.xml file.
I am now out of ideas to get this to work and finally be able to emulate my entire app :) Here is my xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.osly">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" 
      tools:targetApi="33">
      
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If it ever helps, here is the function that is failing to fetch, but since it works well on iOS I don't believe it is wrong:

```
export async function loginResident(email: string, password: string) {
  const item = { email, password };
  const url = `${Config.API_URL}wf/login_resident/${JSON.stringify(item)}`;
//POST Request to Bubble Backend
  const responseFetch = await fetch(Config.API_URL + 'wf/login_resident', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${Config.API_KEY}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(item),
  });

  if (responseFetch.ok) {
    const responseData = await responseFetch.json();
    await cache.store(url, responseData);
  }

  return await cache.get(url);
}
```

If anyone has an idea, omg you'd be my saviour!

Comment: Are you sure the url is being populated correctly on Android?

Comment: Try to catch an error and see the details.